# How to return HTML / components from clientside callbacks?

Tags: plotly-dash

I want to convert a regular (Python) callback to clientside. I'm running into difficulties with outputting to `children` property anything more complicated then a simple string.

The hope was that I could create a new component with `new dash_html_components.Span()`, but this throws an error:

```
Error: An object was provided as `children` instead of a component, string, or number (or list of those). Check the children property that looks something like:
{
  "type": "span",
  "key": null,
  "ref": null,
  "props": {
    "children": "You have clicked THE Button!"
  },
  "_owner": null
}
```

The full code is below. It is possible to set anything other than a string into `children` like this, or what am I doing wrong?

---

```py
import dash_html_components as html
from dash import Dash
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input


app = Dash(prevent_initial_callbacks=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button("THE Button", id="the_button"),
    html.Div(id="the_log"),
])

app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(n_clicks){
        
        // return "You have clicked THE Button!";  // works
        
        // return "You have clicked <strong>THE Button!</strong>";  // works, but escapes the HTML (as expected)
        
        return new dash_html_components.Span({children: "You have clicked THE Button!"});  // doesn't work
        
        // return ["You have clicked ", new dash_html_components.Strong({children: "THE Button!" })];  // the goal
    }
    """,
    Output("the_log", "children"),
    Input("the_button", "n_clicks"),
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: What is the purpose? To render html, or to build component trees?

Comment: @emher Render relatively simple HTML, but with varying structure (cannot just prepare a layout and update text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to write inline HTML code, you could use the `Purify` component from `dash-extensions`. When you pass HTML code to its `html` property, it is rendered inline,

```
from dash import html, Dash, Output, Input
from dash_extensions import Purify

app = Dash(prevent_initial_callbacks=True)
app.layout = html.Div([html.Button("Click me", id="btn"), Purify(id="purify")])
app.clientside_callback("""function(n_clicks){return 'This is <b>html</b>';}""",
                        Output("purify", "html"), Input("btn", "n_clicks"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

Prior to rendering, sanitization is performed using [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify), hence the name of the component.

Comment: Elegant solution +1, much less clunky than the the one I found with constructed JS objects. But also less general (needs this special component), so not always applicable. I'd mark both answers as accepted solutions if I could :-/

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it depends on the use case, hence my initial comment. When it is just html code, I would prefer the Purify component. But if you truly need to construct custom component trees, your proposed solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

After some debugging, I found this to work:

```js
    function(n_clicks){
        return [
            "You have clicked ", 
            {
                type: "Strong", 
                namespace: "dash_html_components",
                props: {children: "THE Button"},
            }, 
            "!"
        ];
        
    }
```